# Make Objects for every item in List

Tags: javascript, oop

I have an array `barcodeList` that stores different barcode numbers. I want to make every single one of them into a different object with the `key` being the barcode numbers and having different properties. Then I want to put them all into one big object `foodItems`. How can I do this.

Also, I realized that numbers can't be used to make variables, so I would want to put a keyword in front of them. Also, the `image` and `ingredient` values of `null` are just placeholders for now.

Wanted Result -

```
foodItems = {
    Data9001: {
        image : null
        ingredients : null
        }
    Data9002: {
        image : null
        ingredients : null
        }

}
```

From `barcodeList = [9001, 9002]`

Any recommends methods to user or keywords would be appreciated as well.

Attempted:

```
barcodeList.push(code)

var Food = function() {
    this.image = "noImage.png"
    this.nutrients = null
    this.ingredients = null
}

var foodItems = {}

for (var i in barcodeList) {
//Some append function
var something = new Food()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation! Added that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the bracket notation to create the keys

```
var barcodeList = [9001, 9002];

var foodItems = {};
barcodeList.forEach(function(item){
  foodItems['Data'+item] = {
      image : null,
      ingredients : null
  };
});

console.log(foodItems);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Is there a way I can implement my `Food constructor` in that code so I don't have to define `image` and `ingredients` manually.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I didn't understand, what do you mean by this
`I realized that numbers can't be used to make variables`

but as per your requirement, you can do something like this

```js
var barcodeList = [9001,9002];
var foodItems = {};

for (var i = 0; i < barcodeList.length; i++) {
    foodItems[barcodeList[i]] = {
        image : null,
        ingredients : null
    }
}

console.log(foodItems)
```

Edited:

As per your code you can do this

```js
var barcodeList = [9001, 9002]
var foodItems = {};

var Food = function() {
    this.image = "noImage.png"
    this.nutrients = null
    this.ingredients = null
}

var foodItems = {}

for (var i = 0; i < barcodeList.length; i++) {
   var something = new Food()
   foodItems[barcodeList[i]] = something;
}

console.log(foodItems);
```

Comment: By that I meant that I cannot do something like
`var 123 = "hello"`

Comment: Thats true, there are certain rules for variables. But numbers can be `key` of objects

Comment: Oh, Thanks for that, I don't need to add underscores in front of them then!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, how far you have gone with your answer. I would use 
the Array.prototype.map() to create an array of Data objects and then use the reduce to concatenate.

Few pointers
As you need keys to begin with Data I would use ['Data'+barcode] to create them.
I will also use the ES6 spread operator to concatenate.

Here is the working code.

```
"use strict"
var barcodeList = [9001, 9002];

var result = barcodeList.map(function(barcode){
    return {
        ['Data'+barcode]: {
            image: null,
            ingredients : null
        }
    }   
}).reduce(function(prevValue,currValue){
    return {...prevValue, ...currValue};
});

console.log ( result);
```